# C++ main() function - start from beginning

Tags: c++, function, return

Suppose I have a C++ program with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

void func() {
//code for doing some stuffs
}

int main() {
int a; //line 8
cin>>a;
if(a==5) {
func();
} //line 12
}
```

In the main() function, after calling the function func() it runs well. But after finishing executing the codes from func() it returns to line 12. But how can I return to line 8 after executing func()? I mean after executing a function, I want the main() function to run from the beginning.

Comment: put the current code in the body of a loop, e.g. a `while` loop.

Comment: I've heard of these mythical structures called loops. Have you?

Comment: use `goto` *evil grin*.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath (-_-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about the basic language feature of program flow control structures (could have been found in any decent textbook).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath: http://www.sherv.net/mr.burns.evil.laugh-emoticon-3717.html

Comment: Using an infinite loop resolves the issue. But is it a good practice?

Comment: @AbdullahShahriar _"But is it a good practice? "_ Well, you can still `break;` the infinite loop, using a certain condition. For embedded devices it's the most common practice at all.

Comment: Well. Then problems solved. :)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath You shouldn't even joke about that. Last thing we need is people taking you seriously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put everything in your main() in a while(true) loop then your program will loop round to line 8 after finishing func().

```
Int main() {
    while(1){
        int a; //line 8
        cin>>a;
        if(a==5) {
            func();
        } //line 12
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic way, set the amount of times you want the LOOP to run...

```
#include<iostream>

 void func()
 {
 }
 const int LOOP = 10  //for example

 int main()
 { 
   for (int i = 0; i < LOOP; i++)
   {
     int a;
     std::cin >> a;

     if (a == 5)
       func();
   }
     return 0;
  }
```